# Prove that the matrix is totally unimodular, for any binary vector $a$

Tags: total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

I need to prove that for every binary column vector $a\in\{0, 1\}^n$, the following matrix is totally unimodular:

$$ A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    I_n & a \\
    a^T & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$

Where $I_n$ is the Identity matrix of size $n$.

I noticed that if the i'th element of $a$ is $0$, I can remove the i'th row and the i'th column of $A$, since it contains only a single non-zero element, so I can assume that $a$ contains only ones.

How can I continue from here?

Comment: You can explicitly find the inverse or the determinant of $A$.

Comment: @Berci How? And why it helps, since I need to check every determinant is $0, 1, -1$, and not just the determinant of $A$

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Consider $n > 3$ and $a = [1,1,\dots,1]^T$ the all $1$ column vector. Then, $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &\dots & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\ \vdots & & \dots & & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ has determinant $-(n-2) \notin \{0,\pm1\}$ because the row-reduced echelon form of $A$ is $$A' = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &\dots & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\ \vdots & & \dots & & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -(n-2)\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &\dots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & & \dots & & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & \dots & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}}_{U}A$$
and $det(A') = det(UA) = det(U)det(A) = det(A)$.